# Why can't I log into MySQL with a new user that has permissions on the database?

Tags: permissions, mysql

I created a user in MySQL but I can't log in with it.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> create user fe_joomla;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> grant all on fe_joomla.* to fe_joomla;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> show grants for fe_joomla;
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for fe_joomla@%                                   |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'fe_joomla'@'%'                    |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `fe_joomla`.* TO 'fe_joomla'@'%' |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

$ mysql -u fe_joomla fe_joomla
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'fe_joomla'
```

I followed this guide. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-grant.aspx

Comment: I don't see where you set a password.

Comment: Try just `mysql -u fe_joomla` without specifying a database; if that works the database does not exist and you must create it before any user can access it. Did it really say `user ''@'localhost'` with nothing in the `''`?? @Michael-sqlbot: he didn't and that's why 1044 not 1045. MySQL supports users with no password, although whether or when you should _use_ them is a different question.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 excellent eye.  I misread the login attempt as `mysql -u fe_joomla -pfe_joomla` and I also overlooked `''@'localhost'` which is why I asked a question that didn't make sense.  Just like empty passwords, there's that nasty empty string user that is created by default in older versions (unless you run `mysql_secure_installation`) is being matched.

Answer (score 1):

Older versions of MySQL had some test accounts with empty usernames that were created by default.  They were mostly harmless, but very problematic.  There was a script called `mysql_secure_installation` that cleaned this up, and it looks like it was not run when your system was set up.

Run this query to confirm:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE user = '';
```

Note that `''` is two single quote characters `'` not a single double quote `"`.

**After ensuring that you have a full backup** for safety, remove those test accounts.  (This should be a perfectly safe operation, but having a backup is good practice.)

```
mysql> DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE user = '';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

The problem with these test accounts is that there is some magical behavior when it comes to matching usernames, and an empty username has a special meaning.  It was a bad feature that was probably originally added to make getting started easier.

After this, your new user should work correctly... but note that you should not create accounts without passwords.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did not enter the command "flush privileges" to activate the new user without restarting.

Comment: I did enter that elsewhere but did not copy it into the question. It didn't seem to help.

Comment: In that case I'm out of ideas - save to observe that, from the error message, MariaDB did not think you did mot provided it a username at all. (I note that you are not using MySQL, MariaDB is a drop-in replacement for MySQL)

Answer (score 0):

I dropped the fe_joomla user and recreated the user as `fe_joomla@localhost` and granted privileges to `fe_joomla@localhost` and it worked. I could use `mysql -u fe_joomla fe_joomla` now.

```
create user fe_joomla@localhost;
grant all on fe_joomla.* to fe_joomla@localhost;
```

Michael's answer would probably work too.